# I want to extract strings contained in text attribute of an xml file

Tags: xml, bash, shell

My xml file is like this

```
  <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="* Please enter Username" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="eQB-cs-m5N">
```

Using sed I am trying to extract the text as

```
sed -n 's/.*text="\([^\"]*\)/\1/p' KHLLoginController.xml
```

I am trying to match the pattern after searching text=" till the first double quotes (") are encountered

Instead of desired Output which is "* Please enter Username"

I am getting the whole line containing the above pattern

- Please enter Username" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="eQB-cs-m5N">

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 sed -n 's/.*text=\("\([^\"]*\)"\).*/\1/p' KHLLoginController.xml
```

For Power Shell

```
$input_path = ‘d:\input.txt’
$output_file = ‘d:\output.txt’
$regex = ‘(text=)("([^"]|"")*")’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*text="\([^\"]*\).*/\1/' filename
```

`-n` and `p` is not necessary